# How can we determine which chromosome came from which parent?

Tags: molecular-genetics, chromosome, epigenetics

In [this article](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-4425/10/4/257/htm) there is a graph (figure 1) describing different levels of methylation in the maternal and paternal chromosomes **after** karyogamy.
How can the researchers identify which chromosome originates from each parent?

Comment: That article is a review, and cites two other reviews for this figure.  [The more recent one](http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/28/8/812.full.pdf+html) is freely available and looks fairly thorough, with more direct references to primary publications.

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way to identify which chromosome came from which parent would be to use sequences of known fragments of parental chromosomes or to use SNP arrays. I hope that I did not miss your question completely.

Regards,

Comment: is that the common way? I learned this subject in a course where they also spoke of sequencing techinques including SNP arrays but they said that teaching how to recognize chromosome origin is out of scope so I assumed there is another way.